# Hadoop 2.4 installation for mac: file configuration

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop. I am trying to set up Hadoop 2.4 on MacBook Pro using Homebrew. I have been following instructions in this web site (http://shayanmasood.com/blog/how-to-setup-hadoop-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks/). I have installed Hadoop on my machine. Now I am trying to configure Hadoop.

One needs to configure the following files according to the website.

- mapred-site.xml
- hdfs-site.xml
- core-site.xml
- hadoop-env.sh

But, it seems that this information is a bit old. In Terminal, I see the following.

```
In Hadoop's config file:
  /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.0/libexec/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh,
  /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.0/libexec/etc/hadoop/mapred-env.sh and
  /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.0/libexec/etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh
$JAVA_HOME has been set to be the output of:
  /usr/libexec/java_home
```

It seems that I have three files to configure here. Am I right on the track? There is information for hadoop-env.sh and mapped-env.sh for configuration. But, I have not seen one for yarn-env.sh. What do I have to do with this file?

The other question is how I access to these files for modification? I receive the following message in terminal right now.

```
-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.0/libexec/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: Permission denied
```

If you have any suggestions, please let me know. Thank you very much for taking your time.

Comment: I just wanna leave this link. This will be helpful for people who look for solutions. http://www.rdatamining.com/tutorials/r-hadoop-setup-guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the configuration files under :

/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.0/libexec/etc/hadoop

[image]

And concerning the permission for the scripts suggested by brew, you also need to change their mode.

In the scripts directory (`/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.0/libexec/etc/hadoop/`)

```
sudo chmod +x *.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking in hadoop/conf/ folder to amend below
mapred-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml,core-site.xml
And you can change permission of hadoop-env.sh to make changes to that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your session is in SSH. Then use the start-all.sh command to start Hadoop.